# Origin doesn't install at all on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, crash, playonlinux

I've tried seemingly everything possible to get Origin to install on my laptop. I've followed everything step by step in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ga2lNM72-Kw. Around 5:50 is the furthest I've got. What happens on his screen, doesn't happen on mine. Granted, I'm using a newer version of POL, Wine, AND Origin. I also have to make my Wine Desktop Win7 or I get an error from Origin saying if it's not Win7, it won't work...so I don't click Vista. I've tried redownloading OriginSetup, I've tried using OriginThinSetup, I even have an older version of Origin (that, when it updates, just freezes when he gets the login prompt...I don't get such a prompt). Every once in a while, I'll get an error message saying something to the affect of "igoproxy has a serious error"

I've tried every combination of system wine, 1.7.35 (most up to date in the video), and 1.9.24 (most updated version I have) with 32 and 64 bit, with Vista and 7.

I've even gone so far as to go into each origin file and check off the "mark files as executable" and tried that as a variation...to no avail.

If it gets to the "Origin is updating" screen, shortly after, the window closes and it prompts me to save the shortcut.

I just can't seem to find anything on Google (went as far as the third page), YouTube, or any previous questions here or Ubuntuforums. It's like I'm the only one having this issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: check this: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26175&iTestingId=95394

Comment: That seemed to have gotten me a bit further. But I'm not sure where to put the IGO32.dll nor how to properly execute the chown command.

Comment: I also figured out how to get to the proper directory, but u+w -R isn't coming up as a command with or without chown

Comment: hi , the correct command is `chmod u+w -R  ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/[Origin directory]` (exchange [] with the correct folder); This command changes the file/directory restrictions, in this case it recursively (-R) adds (w)rite capabilities for the (u)ser.

Comment: I believe the dll hast to go here: ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help so far...still a little lost. Thanks for the command explanation...helped me understand it much better.

The only folders I have in ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files is Common File and Internet Explorer.
The only time I got to am Origin folder is if I went to ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/RedAlert2/drive_c/Program\ Files/Origin
Did I not configure wine correctly?

Comment: no you are litterally on the right path, somehow didn't catch PlayOnLinux being mentioned; sorry for that. Since that's a wrapper script for wine, it is `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/RedAlert2/drive_c` not ` ~/.wine/drive_c`. accordingly you have to adapt the path of above mentioned command. it now would be  `chmod u+w -R ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/RedAlert2/drive_c/Program\ Files/Origin` and for the *.dll  it should be `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/RedAlert2/drive_c/windows/system32/`

Comment: @db429 I pasted the dll file into the system32 file. I ran the command (before I even opened POL...not sure if that may have been an issue) exactly how it should have been (how you typed it out) Origin began to update, but ultimately gave me [this error prompt](https://imgur.com/GJwxoIO).

Any suggestions from here? Should I try OriginSetup files as opposed to the ThinSetup files? The Legacy file is also a thinsetup...which was the one I tried as per Wine HQ.

Comment: *Update* during another installation attempt, "windows" said it couldn't open certain files. When I went down the path myself (not in the terminal) I found it was locked. I went into the nautilus and allowed access. It then seemed to install well, but gave me the same error message as I linked above. But this time, it didn't close immediately. I was able to click the Origin icon and it attempted to open only to close claiming it encountered a serious problem, then ultimately, closed the entire Wine Desktop...then prompted me to save the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Installed both versions of 64 bit Origin and 32 bit origin on Linux mint today, following these instructions:

https://www.pcsteps.com/5110-install-origin-linux-mint-ubuntu-wine/

The 32 bit version played the 32 bit games, but the 64 bit games like Titanfall and star wars battlefront does not load at all.

I think it is a driver issue.... Check that you have a compatible driver from Nvidia or whatever card manufacturer u have...

Comment: Maybe you should add the link you refer also refers to Ubuntu.